# Problemas configurando DDNS a través de No-IP

Tags: dns, router, puertos

**Este es mi problema:**
Tengo un dominio creado en No-IP, y una máquina servidor donde está instalado el cliente (DUC) de No-IP.
Tengo una aplicación instalada en el servidor, a la cual se accede a través del puerto 8089.
En el router configuré DDNS (con los datos de No-IP), abrí el puerto 8089.
El problema es que con las herramientas el puerto me aparece como CERRADO.
El antivirus y el firewall están deshabilitados, el modem es Huawei HG8145V5.

**Esto he intentado:**
Traté de resolverlo, eliminando y volviendo a crear el hostname en No-IP, en vez del puerto 8089 abrí todos los puertos con la opción DMZ, sin resultados... sigue apareciendo como CERRADO el puerto.
Al estar cerrado, cuando desde un navegador intento abrir el dominio con el puerto da error de acceso.
Si utilizo la IP con el puerto (en vez del dominio) tampoco logro acceder a la aplicación.

Ya tengo 4 días preguntando en otros foros y no logro encontrar una respuesta.
Saludos y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Yo no sé nada de esto pero buscaste algún tutorial en Youtube...? Puede que esté se asemeje https://youtu.be/4cGfjVyyo1U

Comment: Ya llevo días en esto, hay muchos tutoriales, incluso en la marca del router (Huawei), a pesar de seguir todas las indicaciones no ha funcionado. Yo lo hice con anterioridad en otro modelo de router y funcionó a la perfección, pero al cambiar de proveedor de internet cambió el modem y ahora tengo este problema.

Comment: Pues hay [respuestas oficiales](https://forum.huawei.com/enterprise/en/cannot-port-forward-on-hg8145v5/thread/628315-100181) del fabricante. Ya de ahí en adelante, depende de ajustes específicos del firmware o restricciones del ISP. No es claro _cómo_ configuraste el router (podemos suponer que no lo hiciste como era) y tampoco sabemos cómo estás probando si el puerto está abierto o no.

Answer (score 0):

La pregunta ya tiene unos meses, la causa del problema era el proveedor de internet (Empresa TotalPlay, en México) que no permite el acceso directo a abrir los puertos, pues tienen un servidor NAS en medio de la conexión, la solución con ellos era contratar una IP Fija para poder abrir los puertos. Opté por cambiar de proveedor, porque no tenían IP disponibles para contratación.

Comment: ¿Seguro que dijeron un servidor NAS?  ¿No seria NAT?

Comment: Si sos el mismo usuario que formuló la pregunta, solicitá [fusionar / combinar tus cuentas](/contact).

Comment: La verdad, no le entendí bien, desconozco el tema, pudo ser NAT. Gracias por tu comentario.